# Highest capacity HDD compatible with late 2011 MacBook Pro optibay

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, sata, hdd

What is the highest capacity hard drive model that would fit and work reliably *in the optical bay* of a 15" late 2011 MacBook Pro ([MacBookPro8,2](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201300))?

As far as I can tell, the issues at play are physical dimensions and the [well-documented SATA III compatibility issues](http://blog.macsales.com/12410-apples-latest-2011-macbook-pro-refresh-using-sata-3-0-6gbs-drives) with this generation of MacBooks.

I purchased a [HN-M101MBB/ST1000LM024](http://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/support/docs/samsung-ds/100698122c.pdf) but, contrary to its data sheet, the drive turned out to be SATA III (6 Gb/s) rather than SATA II (3 Gb/s), and did not work reliably.

Which brings me to the question: which 1TB+ HDD models can I expect to work?

Comment: Is there a question here since you already know the answer? 3Gb/sec is maxed out by EFI.

Comment: @Buscar웃: The question is stated in the very first sentence: What is the highest capacity HDD **model** that would (i.e. is known to) work? A suitable answer would be "1TB Seagate model ABC" or "1.5TB HGST model XYZ" etc.